# R: output "values" directly into dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Simple question here, but I'm having trouble googling to find a correct answer.

I'm using `trapz` from the `pracma` packages to get values for the area under of the curve.

```
AUC1 = trapz(df$x, df$y)
AUC2 = trapz(df$x, df$z)
...
```

Since I only have 7 conditions, I'm doing this manually, resulting in 7 stored values with the following properties:

```
class(AUC1) = "numeric"
typeof(AUC1) = "double"
```

How can I directly output my results into a dataframe rather than list of values? I would like this outcome:

```
1 AUC1    VALUE1
2 AUC2    VALUE2
  ...     ...
7 AUC7    VALUE7
```

But all I can figure out to do now is create a new dataframe and manually input each of the values.

As a followup question, what would be the best way to run `trapz` on multiple values simultaneously (rather an manul input). Would I just want to create a loop?  Thanks!

Comment: what package has `trapz`? also try `data.frame(Values = do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "AUC\\d+"))))`

Comment: Package is pracma.  Your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: make sure that your data is ordered correctly and has no missing values using `pracma::trapz` or you may get wrong results (unless this issue has been fixed). I have used `sfsmisc::integrate.xy` and it seems to avoid ordering and missing data issues, and has a "spline" option.

Comment: Nice tip! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running `trapz` manually for each data.frame, put them in a list and use `lapply` to run `trapz` on all at once

```
#DATA
set.seed(2)
df1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
df2 = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))

#Create a list
mylist = mget(c("df1", "df2"))

#Run trapz on all dataframes in mylist
library(pracma)
data.frame(Values = do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, function(a) trapz(a$x, a$y))))
#       Values
#df1 2.2370598
#df2 0.2684159
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!